# AppleScript to delete emails to specific recipient in macOS Mail

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email

I am currently facing a challenge involving the Mail app on macOS (latest version).

I am looking for assistance in writing an AppleScript (or other viable method) to delete all emails sent to "example@example.com" within e.g. the past five days.

I have tried a few different ways, but perhaps because I have multiple mailboxes and lots of different "sent" folders (albeit grouped in Mail under the name "All Sent") the scripts I've come up with don't do anything.

If anyone has experience or knowledge, or can suggest an alternative approach to achieve this task — e.g. Automator, which also didn't do the trick — I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Comment: We can't write a script for you but folks here can point out issues and other things to try, but we need to see the code you have already come up with. Please add that code to your question, it will go a long way towards solving your problem.